# Joint object in collection transformation is undefined

Tags: meteor

I have this publication with join transformation

```
export var Posts = new Mongo.Collection<Post>(‘posts', {
  transform: function(doc) {
    doc.user = Meteor.users.findOne(doc.userId);
    doc.category = Categories.findOne(doc.categoryId);
    return doc;
  }
});
```

this works well with autopublish, but without it, category object is undefined, can someone help me understand why?
note: Yes I published and subscribed to posts and categories, and I am getting the joint user object, but not the category object.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `transform` function doesn't wait for all the other collections to be loaded. **Do not depend on other collections in the `transform` function.**

When your `posts` collection data arrives at the client, Meteor executes the `transform` function. This could very well be before `Categories` gets synchronized, and that's how `findOne` returns `undefined`. Later, when `Categories` data is finally downloaded to the client, the `transform` function doesn't get reevulated. I guess it's because reevaluation of those functions could easily end up in an endless loop.

For this problem there are two good solutions I can think of:

- the [`reywood:publish-composite`](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package does that on server-side
- wait for all collections to load, and then merge them in `createComponent` on the client-side (assuming you use React).

Comment: Thanks aedm for your answer, but unfortunately I am using Angular, and I tried publish-composite but it didn't give me what I want.